# How to Index child object properties and writing search queries in YDN DB from JSON file data

Tags: ydn-db, ydn-db-fulltext

I have gone through many sites but couldn't able to find any solution. here is my question. I want to index the both child and parent properties from YDN DB.

My Sample JSON data :

```
"dataList":[            
    {   
        "id":1,
        "code":"TN",
        "name":"TestName",
        "city":{
            "cityCode":"ABC",
            "cityName":"ABC City"
        },"country":{
            "countryCode":"NG",
            "countryName":"Nigeria"
        },
        "isOnline":true             
    } 
]
```

YDB Schema and Store :

```
"schema": 
{
  "stores": 
  [    
    {
      "name": "airlineList",
      "keyPath": "airportName",
        "indexes": [
        {
          "keyPath": "airportCode"
        },
        {
          "keyPath": "cityCode"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying store the JSON data into  Indexed DB by indexing the parent and child properties when i try to index the child object (city) properties I couldn't able to filter it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [keyPath as an array](https://yathit.github.io/ydn-db/api/ydn/db/schema.html), for example `['city', 'cityCode']`.